# How to get unique values for a field in a Lucene query?

Tags: java, lucene

My Lucene index consists of 2 fields, one is indexed (not stored) and the other is only stored. I want to get all unique values for the stored field that match a query with the indexed field. My current solution is to iterate through all the hits and add the stored values that match to a hash set. Is there a native way in Lucene to do this?

Example (field_indexed, field_stored):
(x1, y1),
(x1, y2),
(x2, y3),
(x1, y1),
(x1, y2)

A query for x1 should return [y1, y2]